# Sugar ORM cannot query column with boolean values

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'm using Sugar ORM to query a list of apps. I have a boolean column for tagging fields in this using:

```
@Setter @Getter public boolean isNew = false;
```

Now after API call I will update and save the record to tag all new apps and then for display I will just query it using:

```
List<AppsModel> app_list = AppsModel.find(AppsModel.class, "is_new = ?", "true");
```

Problem is that it returns 0 entry where it to have 3 on my end. To check I get all the list and check the column one by one to check its values:

```
List<AppsModel> test = AppsModel.listAll(AppsModel.class);
        for(int i=0;i<test.size();i++){
            Log.e("Test app size", String.valueOf(test.get(i).isNew()));
        }
```

And it returns 3 as expected with true values. I can make use of this loop for list but I don't want to as I want to keep my code clean as possible.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8):

Okay I found the answer [here](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/17) from satyan himself

So basically, using `"true"` will match it as String. So instead use:

```
List<AppsModel> app_list = AppsModel.find(AppsModel.class, "is_new = ?", "1");
```

As SQlite store boolean values as 0 and 1.

Comment: It's not Sugar ORM,SQLite stores boolean value as 0 and 1.
[Reference] (https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)